Estou com problema no cors
Estou codando uma aplicação em java/Spring boot, security  e React , nisso estava tentado fazer cadastro e login, so que na hora que mandava o fetch ele me retornava dizendo que meu cors estava faltando configurações
Erro:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/auth/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Front:

function FormRegister() {
    const [nome, setNome] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [cnpj, setCnpj] = useState(''); 
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const RegisterData = { nome, email, cnpj, password };
        const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_VITAVALORE_API_URL;
        
        if (!apiUrl) {
            console.error('API URL não configurada');
            return;
        }
        
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/auth/register`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    // 'no-cors': 'true',
                },
                
                body: JSON.stringify(RegisterData),
            });
            const result = await response.json();
            
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log("Registro bem-sucedido: \n", result);
                navigate('/Empresa/Home');
            } else {
                console.error("Erro no registro:", result);
                navigate('/auth/register');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Erro na requisição:", error);
        }
    };


Back-end:
package com.VidaPlus.VitaValore.infra.cors;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000") // URL do frontend
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
}

tambem tem configuração do jwt que possa estar dando problema possivelmente , mesmo achando que não, mas vou mandar para desencargo de consiencia
package com.VidaPlus.VitaValore.infra.security;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    SecurityFilter securityFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(@NotNull HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(@NotNull AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}


Também tem outras rotas de get que não funcionam, ex: Foto de erro de outra url
sou novo ainda no java/spring e não sei mais o que fazer , ja tentei até usar o front end integrado com o back pelo statics mas n foi =(

Consegui resolver , depois de bater muito a cabeça decidi criar o cors dentro do  security config,tive ajuda do chatgpt tambem, o codigo ficou assim:
    package com.VidaPlus.VitaValore.infra.security;

import com.VidaPlus.VitaValore.infra.security.CustomUserDetailsService;
import com.VidaPlus.VitaValore.infra.security.SecurityFilter;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    SecurityFilter securityFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(@NotNull HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) 
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults()) // Isso aqui salvou
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(@NotNull AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    // Configuração de CORS personalizada
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000")); // Origem permitida (React)
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")); // Métodos permitidos
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type")); // Headers permitidos
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true); // Permitir envio de cookies e credenciais

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

